# How to query sections with questions and their answers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am creating a questionaire screen and I need to display sections with questions along with the user's response. Here's my model:

```
** Section *****
 public int SectionID { get; set; }
 public string SectionText { get; set; }

** Question ****
 public int QuestionID { get; set; }
 public int SectionID { get; set; }
 public string QuestionText { get; set; }
 public bool Required { get; set; }
 public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

** Response ****
 public int ResponseID { get; set; }
 public int UserID { get; set; }
 public int QuestionID { get; set; }
 public string AnswerValue { get; set; }
 public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
```

How do I grab this thru LINQ or another approach to display the following:

```
Section1: User Info
        Question 1. Name:  Bob Smith
        Question 2. Phone: 999-999-9999

Section2: User Tasks
         Question 1. Role: Engineer
         Question 2. Location: Baltimore
```

I tried the following (deos not work):

```
var sections = from b in db.Sections.Include(s => s.Questions.Select(q => q.Responses.Where(r => r.userId == 1))
                            orderby b.SectionOrder
                            select b;
```

Comment: how are you linking Questions with Sections?

Comment: I just updated my question. "SectionId" was missing in the Question model that relates it to Section.

Comment: One last question. I noticed when there are no answers, it returns no questions..is there an equivalent to a left/right outer join for the LINQ? To return all questions if there join to responses?

Answer (score 1):

```
int userId = 1;
var query = from s in db.Sections
            join r in db.Responses.Where(x => x.UserID == userId)
                   on s.SectionID equals r.Question.SectionID into g
            select new SectionModel
            {
                ID = s.SectionID,
                Name = s.SectionText,
                Results = from x in g
                          orderby x.Question.DisplayOrder
                          select new QuestionResultModel
                          {
                              Index = x.Question.DisplayOrder,
                              Question = x.Question.QuestionText,
                              Answer = x.AnswerValue
                          }
            };

  return View(query.ToList());
```

*Update* sample of ViewModel:

```
public class SectionModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<QuestionResultModel> Results { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionResultModel
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Displaying:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourApplication.Models.SectionModel>

@foreach (var s in Model)
{
    <div>Section @s.ID : @s.Name</div>

    foreach (var r in s.Results)
    {
        <div>Question @r.Index. @r.Question : @r.Answer</div>    
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a new model for the view called quiz that has the properties: sectionId,sectiontext, ICollection<Result> Results (created a result model too).. Received the following error:

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`6[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String,System.String]]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[COPSGMIS.Models.Quiz]'.

Comment: Not sure how to wrap the results in order to display it to the view (MVC)? i'm lost.

Comment: @Chaka you need viewmodel for that, or use dynamic viewbag. Also I don't know you are trying to do, because there was no dictionary usage in my sample

Comment: Can you give me a example? Whats a difference between viewmodel from a model?

Comment: @Chaka viewmodel is the object which you pass to view, model is a domain entity

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example and explanation..I really appreciate the help and willingness to share your knowledge.

Comment: One last question. I noticed when there are no answers, it returns no questions..is there an equivalent to a left/right outer join for the LINQ? To return all questions if there join to responses?

Comment: @Chaka `join...into` is an equivalent of left join. In sample above you will get result for sections event if there is no question or answers.